# Proof of inequality harmonic progression

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $n$ be least positive integer for 
which
$1+ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} +\dots> 4n$
prove that  $20< n< 60$.

attempt:
I could prove less than 60 by hsikg inequality $\ln(1+x) < x$ but for the lower part of inequality that is to prove 
$n> 20$ am stuck?

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{1}{n}<\log\left(\frac{2n+1}{2n-1}\right)=2\operatorname{arctanh}\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)$ gives that $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}$ is less than $\log(2n+1)$, and the comparison with a piecewise-constant function (or just $\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)<\frac{1}{n}$) gives that $H_n$ is greater than $\int_{1}^{n+1}\frac{dx}{x}=\log(n+1)$. In particular the least $n$ such that $H_n>4$ is between $\frac{e^4-1}{2}$ and $e^4-1$, hence between $26$ and $54$. Actually such $n$ is $31$.

Comment: can we do without hyperbolic fucntion?

Comment: @maveric: yes, you may invoke the Hermite-Hadamard inequality. It leads precisely to the same outcome.

Comment: could you explain pleae? Hermite inequality?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%E2%80%93Hadamard_inequality

Comment: yes i read. but how to apply here?

Comment: @maveric: In the obvious way: $$\log(2n+1)=\int_{1/2}^{n+1/2}\frac{dx}{x}\stackrel{HH}{>}H_n.$$